# Requires= in systemd unit does not work as intended, both units are started simultaneously

Tags: systemd, podman

I'm trying to force one unit to run to completion before another unit starts, and all docs say that I should trust Requires= but it's not working as advertised.

Here is the actual unit I'm starting (it's generated from a quadlet).

```
# Automatically generated by /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/podman-system-generator
# 
[Unit]
Description=Traefik
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Requires=podman-volume-restore@systemd-acme.service
SourcePath=/etc/containers/systemd/traefik.container
RequiresMountsFor=%t/containers
RequiresMountsFor=/var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml
RequiresMountsFor=/var/opt/traefik/dynamic.toml
Requires=acme-volume.service
After=acme-volume.service

[X-Container]
ContainerName=traefik
Image=docker.io/traefik:v2.10
Volume=/var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml:Z
Volume=/var/opt/traefik/dynamic.toml:/var/opt/traefik/dynamic.toml:Z
Volume=acme.volume:/var/opt/traefik/letsencrypt/:Z
PublishPort=80:80
PublishPort=443:443
EnvironmentFile=/var/opt/traefik/environment
Exec=--configFile=/var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml

[Service]
Restart=always
Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
KillMode=mixed
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=%t/%N.cid
ExecStopPost=-/usr/bin/podman rm -f -i --cidfile=%t/%N.cid
Delegate=yes
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
SyslogIdentifier=%N
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman run --name=traefik --cidfile=%t/%N.cid --replace --rm --cgroups=split --sdnotify=conmon -d -v /var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml:Z -v /var/opt/traefik/dynamic.toml:/var/opt/traefik/dynamic.toml:Z -v systemd-acme:/var/opt/traefik/letsencrypt/:Z --publish 80:80 --publish 443:443 --env-file /var/opt/traefik/environment docker.io/traefik:v2.10 --configFile=/var/opt/traefik/traefik.toml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target default.target
```

Note that it has the line `Requires=podman-volume-restore@systemd-acme.service`.

Here is that unit `/etc/systemd/system/podman-volume-restore@.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=podman volume import %i
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
EnvironmentFile=/etc/podman-volume-backup/environment
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/podman-volume-restore.bash %i
Restart=on-failure
KillMode=process
TimeoutStopSec=300
```

When I run `systemctl start traefik` and check the logs for both units I see that traefik starts simultaneously as podman-volume-restore. It's not at all waiting for it to exit as the docs say it should.

What is wrong with my dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke too soon. I had missed that Requires only works in order if you also specify After=.

So now after changing the After line to `After=network-online.target podman-volume-restore@systemd-acme.service` it works as intended.